# Building NodeJS using Gradle

Tags: node.js, gradle

I'm very new to Gradle. I started reading about it yesterday. I found an example build.gradle that builds a node application. I'm a little bit confused in the contents of the file. I'm not sure which ones are reserved or predefined words. One of the strings is `node`. It wasn't used somewhere but I figured out it was needed by the node plugin.

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'base'
    apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node' // gradle-node-plugin

    node {
        /* gradle-node-plugin configuration
        https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md

        Task name pattern:
        ./gradlew npm_<command> Executes an NPM command.
        */

        // Version of node to use.
        version = '10.14.1'

        // Version of npm to use.
        npmVersion = '6.4.1'

        // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
        // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
        download = true
    }

    npm_run_build {
        // make sure the build task is executed only when appropriate files change
        inputs.files fileTree('public')
        inputs.files fileTree('src')

        // 'node_modules' appeared not reliable for dependency change detection (the task was rerun without changes)
        // though 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' should be enough anyway
        inputs.file 'package.json'
        inputs.file 'package-lock.json'

        outputs.dir 'build'
    }

    // pack output of the build into JAR file
    task packageNpmApp(type: Zip) {
        dependsOn npm_run_build
        baseName 'npm-app'
        extension 'jar'
        destinationDir file("${projectDir}/build_packageNpmApp")
        from('build') {
            // optional path under which output will be visible in Java classpath, e.g. static resources path
            into 'static'
        }
    }

    // declare a dedicated scope for publishing the packaged JAR
    configurations {
        npmResources
    }

    configurations.default.extendsFrom(configurations.npmResources)

    // expose the artifact created by the packaging task
    artifacts {
        npmResources(packageNpmApp.archivePath) {
            builtBy packageNpmApp
            type 'jar'
        }
    }

    assemble.dependsOn packageNpmApp

    String testsExecutedMarkerName = "${projectDir}/.tests.executed"

    task test(type: NpmTask) {
        dependsOn assemble

        // force Jest test runner to execute tests once and finish the process instead of starting watch mode
        environment CI: 'true'

        args = ['run', 'test']

        inputs.files fileTree('src')
        inputs.file 'package.json'
        inputs.file 'package-lock.json'

        // allows easy triggering re-tests
        doLast {
            new File(testsExecutedMarkerName).text = 'delete this file to force re-execution JavaScript tests'
        }
        outputs.file testsExecutedMarkerName
    }

    check.dependsOn test

    clean {
        delete packageNpmApp.archivePath
        delete testsExecutedMarkerName
    }
```

Also, how is the build.gradle parsed? I'm also wondering how it is able to magically download node and npm tools.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, I suggest you trim it down to a specific issue. Your `build.gradle` script is written in Groovy. The `node` keyword is not actually a keyword, it is a "task" in gradle terms, and it is provided by the dependency you reference in your question. This is a pretty complex example to use for learning gradle, you may want to take a step back and go through some basic gradle tutorials first.

Comment: Got it. I didn't know it was a complex example I found. Thank you.

Comment: I mostly agree with @JakeHolzinger, but `node` in the example is not a task, but an extension to define overall settings for the `'com.moowork.node'` plugin. This actually shows one of the major Gradle issues for new users. It requires a broad understanding of both the Gradle features and the concepts of the applied plugins as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @LukasKörfer, I'm not familiar with the plugin in question.

Comment: Thank you @LukasKörfer. I quite agree with what you said. The docs I found to learn Gradle weren't enough. Maybe I shouldn't have jumped directly to plugins. It was just that I'm interested in building a NodejS since I wanted to see how it would fit in our devops ci/cd pipeline.

Comment: Hey @devwannabe 
Just one stupid question. What stands for packageNpmApp?
This should change in my case right? Is this the project name?Like name of my springboot is Test1 now inside it. I have made the react-app and named it frontend . What should I use in that case?

Comment: It's just like a function name. Btw, I remember I got rid of using build.gradle few months after I posted that. I found out from my teammate that he only did that as a proof of concept. I went back to building a nodejs app using unix shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very general synopsis:

- Gradle aims to hide away the logic from developers.
- Most `*.gradle` files contain configuration **blocks** (`closures`) to specify *HOW* logic should run.
- Plugins augment gradle with more *configurable* logic.
- Also, 'convention over configuration' is a practice emphasize in gradle and its plugins, providing sensible defaults to minimize developers' configuration efforts.
- The [`com.moowork.node`](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md) plugin is configured through the `node` extension block.
- [Extension blocks](https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/#modeling_dsl_like_apis) are gradle's way to allow plugins to add more *'reserved'* words to the standard gradle model.
- The `download = true` configuration tells the plugin to download node (`version = '10.14.1'`) and nmp (`npmVersion = '6.4.1'`) in your project's root (unless you override its defaults as well).
- The download of these tools will occur when any of the plugin's task is invoked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your snippet only `true` is keyword, the other things are methods or getters coming from Gradle or Node JS plugin:

- `apply plugin: ...` is a method from `org.gradle.api.Project.apply(java.util.Map<String, ?>)`
- `node` is a method autogenerated by Gradle with signature `void node(Closure<com.moowork.gradle.node.NodeExtension>)` (method accepting a code block), see https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/moowork/gradle/node/NodeExtension.groovy
- `node { version = ... }` - `version`, `npmVersion` are fields from `NodeExtension` class
- other things similarly, everything is a method or a field. If you're using IntelliJ, use Ctrl+mouse click to navigate to the originating method/field declaration.